# How do I implement this Oracel SQL graph query in Python code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to code the Python equivalent of this Oracle SQL command:

```
c.execute('select from_node_id, to_node_id, link_length  from link order by from_node_id')
== sql result
A, B, 10
A, C, 10
A, D, 5
B, C, 5
B, D, 10
```

My code attempt:

```
#test1
data = [{col1: {col2:col3}} for (col1, col2, col3) in c.fetchall()]
print : [{'A': {'B': 10}}, {'A': {'C': 10}}] 

error : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

#test2
graph = print( ", ".join( repr(e) for e in data )) 
[x for x in graph if x is not None]

error : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

#test3
graph = {{'A': {'B': 10}}, {'A': {'C': 10}}}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

My desired output:

```
graph = {
'A': {'B': 10, 'C': 10, 'D': 5},
'B': {'C': 5, 'D': 10}
 }
```

THX...

ADD question code

```
1. SQL RESULT 
= A
  B
  C
2. need python code
result = {'A': infinity, 'B': infinity, 'C': infinity}
```

LAST question code

```
1. SQL RESULT 
= A
  B
  C

parents = {}
for i in p_list:
    for x in i:
        parents.setdefault(x,0)
        parents[x]+= None
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

i need py code
parents = {'A': None, 'B': None, 'C': None}
```

THX PLZ

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: i try code

d_list  = c.execute("select *  from test ").fetchall()
    costs = {}
    for i in d_list:
        if i not in costs.keys():
            costs[i] = 0
        costs[i] += infinity

result 
{('A',): inf, ('B',): inf, ('C',): inf, ('D',): inf}}

Comment: @python_user: Don't edit your comments to user into the question.

Comment: @smci I dont get it, I only deleted what was noise, I did not add anything, the edit I made is this for clarity https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67867072/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u could try this

```
d_list = (('A', 'B', 10),
('A', 'C', 10),
('A', 'D', 5),
('B', 'C', 5),
('B', 'D', 10),)

res = {}
for d in d_list:
  x1,x2,x3 = d
  res.setdefault(x1,{})
  res[x1].setdefault(x2,0)
  res[x1][x2] += x3

# {'A': {'B': 10, 'C': 10, 'D': 5}, 'B': {'C': 5, 'D': 10}}
```

```
d_list = (('A', 'B', 'C','D'),('A', 'B', 'C','D'),)
sums = {}
for i in d_list:
    for x in i:
        sums.setdefault(x,0)
        sums[x]+= 1
# {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'D': 2}
```

Comment: Is this even possible?

sql result : 2190001100

 costs = {}
    costs["2190001100"] = infinity

parents = {} 
    parents["2190001100"] = None

Comment: I got little confuse what exactly u do here by this.Is this original code here "costs = {} costs["2190001100"] =..."

Comment: sql result : A, B, C, D, E, F, G
costs = {'A': infinity, 'B': infinity, 'C': infinity, 'D': infinity, 'E': infinity, 'F': infinity, 'G': infinity, 'H': infinity}

THX

Comment: i still not really understand what exactly you want to do.Are u say this can be more  layers? the source data may look like this ?`(
('A', 'B','E','F', 10),
('A', 'C','E','F', 10),
('A', 'D','E','F', 5),
('B', 'C','E','F', 5),
('B', 'D','E','F', 10),
)`  what's the input what's the output you wish?

Comment: Sorry for not speaking English. I want to implement this.

1. SQL SELECT RESULT 
 A
 B
 C
 D

2. Necessary result(python code)
result= {'A': infinity, 'B': infinity, 'C': infinity, 'D': infinity}


thanks.

Comment: i change my answer.Is the new  "d_list" look like what you want?

Comment: Thank you very much.
Be happy
I love you

Comment: i am glad to help

Comment: `parents[x]+= something` in here im guess you add is a str not int,if what you add is a num,you need to transfer it such as `int(something)` or `float(something)`.if is not num you need change the 0 part to fit your need`sums.setdefault(x,0)`

Comment: Thank you very much.
have a good night
good luck